# covariance of pdf

Tags: probability-distributions, covariance

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}\tfrac 8 3(xy) & \textsf{whereas } 0<x<1 , x<y<2x \\ 0 & \textsf{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

I need to calculate covariance. I managed to calculate that $E(X)$ is $4/5$ and $E(XY)$ is $1$. However I cannot get number for $E(Y)$ because of its boundry. Any suggestions on how to solve for $E(Y)$?

Comment: It would certainly help if you provided the boundary, and used proper formatting. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The bounds were there; just lost in poor formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Since the function appears to be a joint **pdf**, the interval $0<x< 1$ and $x<y<2x$ means that

$$\mathsf E(X) = \int\limits_0^1\int\limits_x^{2x} \tfrac 8 3 xy\cdot x \operatorname d y\operatorname d x ~=~\frac 4 5\quad\color{green}\checkmark$$

$$\mathsf E(XY) = \int\limits_0^1\int\limits_x^{2x} \tfrac 8 3 xy\cdot xy \operatorname d y\operatorname d x ~\neq ~ 1$$

$$\mathsf E(Y) = \int\limits_0^1\int\limits_x^{2x} \tfrac 8 3 xy\cdot y \operatorname d y\operatorname d x$$